# What could be the causes of DNS Client Event error in windows log?

Tags: windows-7, router, dns, cable

Long story short(and most likely the cause). Recently had work done on my cable in front of my house, and they screwed it up several times. for about a week, looked like i could stop complaining to them.

All of a sudden I'm getting internet disconnects all the time and random. No rhyme or reason, although a lot happen between 8pm and 11pm.

I noticed in my windows log when ever one occurs, i get a DNS Client Event error.

I'm fighting the cable company to replace it properly, they keep patching it.
The only thing i really changed on my computer was a video driver update, not sure if this could cause the issue.

Why i wait for this awful company to replace my cable, what else could i check?
Could it be a virus or maybe my cell phone connected to the wifi, is comcast throttling me(not doing anything besides a few online games)?
Could it be some type of interference from a neighbor? 
I did try to go into the router and change the primary DNS to 8.8.8.8, but the issue still occured later that night.

I've checked all the connections inside and outside. And also my TV experiences issues with sound and video pixelation, usually have to change the channel for it to correct itself.

Edit:
Also, some of the time, the cable modem(i have a separate wireless router) would show a disconnection, the connection lights would go out and have to reset itself.

Comment: Your issue sounds like a client problem (Windows OS issue) to me. However first thing I would try is: forget about forwarding your DNS requests to your Router and then going to 8.8.8.8, but instead going to your local network connection properties and setting the DNS Primary here to 8.8.8.8


Could I have the whole DNS Client Event Error pasted somewhere here so I can read it please?

Comment: At work now, so wont be able to get a list till later. But i did read a lot of the messages and they were from many different apps calling out to the internet. I may have also set the local network to 8.8.8.8 already, i was in there yesterday afternoon.

Comment: Just noted above the cable modem would sometimes show a disconnection, usually if the disconnect was long enough.

Comment: Yeah I guess if you've set the local network properties to 8.8.8.8 and the internet connection is disconnect for a period then the DNS client would error as it cannot reach the outside world (8.8.8.8) so that does make sense and ties in with the issues your having from the ISP.

Comment: Had lots of trouble last night, i rebooted everything(includiung the cable tv box) and ran iponfig release renew and flush. And the problems seem to go away. We'll see when i get home today. Also could multiple grounds cause an issue? i noticed they added a new grounding outside when they replaced the cable, it was already grounded inside to the cold water pipe.